# Moment js date format issue

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a moment object and I do like

```
let formatted = momentObj.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ");
```

yet, the output is "2017-08-02A01:00+00:00" instaed of expected "2017-08-02T01:00Z"

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape T & Z like this:

```
let formatted = momentObj.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm[Z]");
```

Comment: it worked. Is it mandatory? I mean, I can't honestly remember but I have the sensation that in some situation it worked without escaping

Comment: Not always. I think `T` is allowed without escaping, but it is best to escape such text since they might decide to add support to something that gives `T` a new meaning. So from the perspective of avoiding issues in future, you *should* always escape strings while using `format`.

Comment: Pretty exhaustive. Thank you